# WP enqueue method fails to load custom scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

Just need a little info on WP en queue, I've followed a few tutorials on various websites as I'm a very basic web designer I mainly work with HTML CSS at least this is what I best understand.

I can't best explain where I have gone wrong but I can post the code for people to view to show you if I have done this correctly. I'm currently building the site locally using WAMP if that helps anyone. I am calling the Jquery from Google CDN I've already de-registered the jQuery that comes with WordPress(because I'm not sure it is using the latest version).

I've re-registered it but even a simple Jquery file doesn't load. at the moment I'm trying to load the scroll to anchor jQuery file.

Here is the functions.php code

```
<?php function vstep_scripts_basic()
  {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );



wp_register_script( 'jquery.anchor', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.anchor.js', array( 'jquery' ) );  


wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.anchor' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'vstep_scripts_basic' );
?>
```

Now this also shows up in the browsers  page so his says to me that it is loading correctly but still the Jquery doesn't work.

```
<script type='text/javascript'src='http://localhost/wordpresshttp//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/vstep/js/jquery.anchor.js?ver=3.5'></script>
```

My website navigates correctly but doesn't include the smooth scrolling effect. The HTML version works fine but the wordpress version doesn't I do not think this is a simple error with the code as it's just a copy paste job from HTML to wordpress changing the paths and locations. besides the website is all one page scrolling from to to bottom.

My thoughts,  Is the ver?3.5 at the end of the anchor.jquery causing a problem?
Have I unregistered the jquery incorrectly ( the scrolling effect came bundled with jquery 1.9.1 hence why I'm using 1.9.1 instead of 2.0.0 )

Are the paths correct for use on a local host?

Is it get_template_uri or get_plugin?

I just can't figure this out any help would be most appreciated.

Thankyou~

TUMTUM

Comment: it is a  [bad practice to load](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/) jquery from google API...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your having a typo in the script url: `http//`

Change

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );
```

to

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );
```

or

```
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, false );
```

Comment: And this is why at times I hate my life as a web designer... it seems to be working. This is a good example of looking way past the mark. In this case the "mark-up" haha.  Thank you I need some sleep now.